# Gauge transformations and the angular momentum operator?

Tags: electromagnetism, angular-momentum, gauge-theory

In momentum space the complete angular momentum operator $J^{\mu\nu}$ can be written as

$$J^{\mu\nu}=p^\mu\partial_p^\nu-p^\nu\partial_p^\mu-iS^{\mu\nu}$$

where $S^{\mu\nu}$ is the spin operator

$$S^{\mu\nu}=i(\epsilon^\mu\partial_\epsilon^\nu-\epsilon^\nu\partial_\epsilon^\mu)$$

and $p^\mu,\epsilon^\mu$ are momentum and polarization vectors respectively. E.g. in electro dynamics the polarization vector $\epsilon^\mu$ is related to the vector potential and a gauge transformation can be written as

$$\epsilon^\mu\to\epsilon^\mu+\alpha p^\mu$$

for any $\alpha$. Therefore, we can think of performing the above gauge transformation on the spin operator and obtain:

$$
\begin{align}
S^{\mu\nu}\to S'^{\mu\nu}&=i((\epsilon^\mu+\alpha p^\mu)\partial_{\epsilon+\alpha p}^\nu-(\epsilon^\nu+\alpha p^\nu)\partial_{\epsilon+\alpha p}^\mu)\\
&=i(\epsilon^\mu\partial_{\epsilon}^\nu+\frac{1}{\alpha}\epsilon^\mu\partial_{ p}^\nu+\alpha p^\mu\partial_{\epsilon}^\nu+ p^\mu\partial_{p}^\nu-\epsilon^\nu\partial_{\epsilon}^\mu-\frac{1}{\alpha}\epsilon^\nu\partial_{ p}^\mu-\alpha p^\nu\partial_{\epsilon}^\mu- p^\nu\partial_{ p}^\mu)
\end{align}
$$
where we used $\partial_{\epsilon+\alpha p}^\mu=\partial_{\epsilon}^\mu+\frac{1}{\alpha}\partial_{p}^\mu$.

I find it a bit strange that if we apply another gauge transformation e.g. $\epsilon^\mu\to\epsilon^\mu+\beta p^\mu$, the new terms that weren't there before will start producing extra summands as well... I wonder if the above is the correct way to apply a gauge transformation to the angular momentum operator?